# Creating a permanent static overlay for QGraphicsView scene

Tags: qt, overlay, qgraphicsview, qpixmap, paintevent

I am making an app using Qt (currently 4.8) which displays a literal map from a large number of QGraphicsScene items. I would like to annotate the view with a scale. My requirement for the scale is that it is permanently fixed w.r.t the viewport widget. It needs to be updated whenever the view scale changes (zoom in, etc). There are other possible overlay items as well (compass, etc) so I'd prefer a generic solution.

I have looked at earlier questions around this which suggest:

- using the ItemIgnoresTransform
- using an overlay pixmap.

I tried IgnoresTransform but that way didn't work right: I couldn't figure out how to fix it in place in (say) the bottom corner of the viewport and was having some difficulty getting the text and lines always displaying in the correct size.

I scrapped that and subclassed QGraphicsView, adding an overlay pixmap by reimplementing the paintEvent (calls original one, then paints the overlay pixmap on top), and an alignment option to indicate where it goes. Coding some pixmap paint code produces a usable scale on the view. Yay!  ... but it doesn't work with scrolls - I get "shattered" renderings of the scale all over, or sometimes no scale at all. I think this is because QGraphicsView::scrollViewportBy() uses viewport()->scroll() so I wondered if switching to ViewportSmartUpdate would help, but it doesn't help enough. I'd prefer not to switch to ViewportFullUpdate as that would likely slow the app down too much (there are millions of items in the scene and that would require a full repaint just to move around).

So. Any ideas from here? Would adapting my pixmap code to write to a new mostly-transparent Widget that is overlaid on the viewport be a better way?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it may not be the best way of doing this, in the past I've added custom widgets to the window that holds the QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene, which have the same graphic style as the QGraphicObjects in the scene. When the view is then used to move objects in the scene, or the scene itself, the items on the window remain in the same place.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, after playing around, that does seem to be the best way. Thanks.